# Node & M1: missing symbol called

Tags: homebrew, apple-silicon, rosetta

i really need your help.

I am having problems with node (v16.8.0) and my macOS with arm processor. Every time i want to run the backend of [this project](https://github.com/animo/simple-demo) i get this:

```
dyld[17378]: missing symbol called
```

I have already followed the whole [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65342769/install-node-on-m1-mac) on this other post.
I tried to do a clean install of node for arm with rosetta2, but if I run `node -p "process.arch"` I always get `x64`.

I've also tried with a more aggressive approach:

- Removed all Node files, everything, in all folders and subfolder making sure that node was completely uninstalled
- Removed the libraries and removed the dependencies
- Re-installed Node with brew (using arch)
- Re-installed libraries and dependencies

Since I have already removed and reinstalled node 5 times just today, could you please help me to find out how can I solve this problem? Thank you!

Steps i followed:

```
$ arch -x86_64 zsh
$ nvm use system
$ nvm cache clear
$ nvm uninstall 16 
$ nvm install 16   
$ nvm use 16       
$ rm -rf node_modules
$ yarn cache clean
$ yarn install
```

Comment: What does „ clean install of node for arm with rosetta2“ mean, are you installing the arm or the Intel version? The linked post explains how to install the Intel version, so „x64“ as output is to be expected.

Comment: Hello, i'm installing the arm version. As far as i so the dyld error is caused by an incompatible node version. The guide actually shows how to install node for arm, also, i was looking to this one (which is also not working): https://gist.github.com/adrienjoly/e29a6e73fb7e701eefd80ff9bde9abeb

Comment: Instead of linking to instructions and letting us guess, please add the instructions you actually used.

Comment: Fair point, here you go ;)

Comment: If you run all of this in a x64 zsh, x64 binaries got installed.

Comment: Oki got it, but i'm still very confused about the `dyld[17378]: missing symbol called` error. Something is not right, so should i try in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again, found the solution.

The solution was:

- Clean up again everything. This means uninstall and delete all files for: yarn, npm, nvm, and node
- Re-install everything via homebrew
- Delete all node_modules
- Re-run yarn/npm install in the repo

Comment: wat, sounds painfual(((((((((